# Template of root control

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have custom control named Frame (public class Frame : ContentControl, IDisposable). Frame in constructor defines DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Frame); and Frame template is in Generic.xaml resource. Now In some other project I use frame that is in Silverlight.Controls and if I set my main page that the root element is frame like this

```
<ShellFrame:Frame x:Class="Modules.Adresar.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Modules.Adresar.ViewModel"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ShellFrame="clr-namespace:Silverlight.Controls;assembly=Silverlight.Controls" mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Converter={StaticResource VMIndexerConverter}, ConverterParameter=AdresarVM}"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=s:AdresarViewModel}" x:Name="MainFrame">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutMain">


</Grid>
```

I can't edit template of frame. Blend is showing al edit template menu items disabled.  But If I put frame inside layout root grid in normal user control then everything is ok.. like this

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ShellFrame="clr-namespace:Silverlight.Controls;assembly=Silverlight.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Adresar.Test"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ShellFrame:Frame Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Does enybody knows why this is happening?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changing your Frame control to be based on `UserControl` instead of `ContentControl` should fix the behavior you're seeing in Blend. I'm not sure how you're using your control, but if you can't utilize a UserControl you might want to include some context.